# How to get negative lookahead in regex to accept more words

Tags: regex, splunk

I am trying to get some data for Splunk.

From this:

```
this my line - Fine (R/S)
more date - I like this (not)
date - output (yes)
```

I like to get all data from `-` to the end of line, but not the data in parentheses if it contains `not` or `yes`, so data in `group1` should be:

```
Fine (R/S)
I like this
output
```

I have tried some like this:

```
- (.+) (?!(not|yes))
```

But this gives:

```
Fine
I like this
output
```

Or This:

```
- (.+)(?!not)
```

Gives:

```
Fine (R/S)
I like this (not)
output (yes)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this,

```
- ((?:(?!\((?:not|yes)\)).)*)(?=\s|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aH8oW4/3)

or

```
- (.*?)(?=\s+\((?:not|yes)\)|$)
```

This would capture all the chars until a `space(yes)` or `space(no)` or end of the line is reached.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aH8oW4/2)

Comment: Why `-.*(?!not)` doesn't work? (If I want to match everything not followed by "not", for example).

Comment: Because `-.*(?!not)` matches the whole line until the last. At the last, there isn't a not string, so the above would provide a match.

Comment: So can you please explain what's the workaround you did?

Comment: Avinash: you may want to remove first regex as 2nd one is the right one meeting OP's requirement +1

Comment: a little change in the first one, `- ((?:(?!\((?:not|yes)\)).)*)(?=\s|$)`

Comment: Thanks, both regex works, but I have to take some care to the `not`, it could be some like this `(real 22 ms)` so the I change `not` with `real[^)]+` to get all characters within the parentheses.